# Trying to override the search query doesn't have any effect

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have shortened my code example to:

```
function custom_search($q)
{
    $args = array(
        array(
            'key'  => '_price',
            'value'     => array( 50, 500 ),
            'compare'   => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    );
    $q->set("meta_query", $args);
}
add_action("woocommerce_product_query", "custom_search");
```

I am trying to set the category to specific category from my custom made form but this doesn't seems to work. The value is set in the `query_vars` but the result on my search page is not correct. Using `woocommerce` plugin and trying tho filter products.
**EDIT** I`ve edited my code example with some that is considered as working but still in my case it shows no products.